Where remove or set initial rows for database in Django?
I store some temporary data in a database linked to a web socket. After a server reboot, the web sockets die and I want to delete all data from the corresponding table. Tell me where ideologically this should be done or such data should not be stored in the database at all?
I tried putting this block in AppConfig.ready but the console warning says it's the wrong place.
from django.apps import AppConfig

class GameConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'game'

    def ready(self) -> None:
        LobbySetting = self.get_model('LobbySetting')
        LobbySetting.objects.all().delete()

Warning in console:
RuntimeWarning: Accessing the database during app initialization is discouraged. To fix this warning, avoid executing queries in AppConfig.ready() or when your app modules are imported.
  warnings.warn(self.APPS_NOT_READY_WARNING_MSG, category=RuntimeWarning)


I did not testet it, but may be post_migrate signal could be a viable option: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/signals/#post-migrate

When you think of storing data, there is no better solution than a database, its that simple. Although, there are many options that would make one achieve a better result, in this case a NoSQL database (REDIS, Mongo) would fit better, imo.

As for the clearing data issue, there are other ways. I do not know exactly how your app works, so its hard to say. But for instance, how about a job scheduler to clear all data that’s one week old (or similar).
